# Include gson in my java program

Tags: java, classpath, gson

So far I have only used standard libraries in my programs. I'm just making a simple console application and I'm not using any IDE, just simple text editor (because I don't need anything more complex at the moment).

I don't know where to put jar file I've downloaded and I also don't know how to call it correctly. I've read something about include path? But I'm not sure if I understand.

I just have simple folder structure like so:

- Project

  - Class.java
  - Class.class
  - gson-2.2.1.jar

I've tried with this:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
```

But I get that it doesn't exist.

Comment: You need the gson jar to be in your classpath (both when compiling and when executing).

Comment: Jinx See, @Jeremy Heilers answer. Oh, and start using some kind of IDE.

Comment: @esej This is just a little something that I need to get done quickly, I don't intend to go serious with java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer assumes you are using the `javac` and `java` commands in a *nix environment.

To compile your code you need to put the jar and your Java files on to the classpath with the `-cp` flag. For this small example, you really only need to provide the Java file that has your main method. This is because the compiler will look for any Java files it needs to compile along with `YourClass.java` by searching for them on the classpath.

```
javac -cp /path/to/java/files:/path/to/gson-2.2.1.jar YourClass.java
```

To run your code you need to do the same thing but only refer to the class with your main method.

```
java -cp /path/to/class/files:/path/to/gson-2.2.1.jar YourClass
```

Keep in mind that the `/path/to/java/files` and `/path/to/class/files` directories must point to the *root* directory of your packages (if you using packages, which you should).

Comment: Probably obvious, but just in case it isn't, this is if the gson.jar is in the same directory as your .java. It it isn't, make certain you give the correct path from the current directory to your jars or it still won't find it :)

Comment: Thanks, but can I somehow avoid using class path when running the program since user would have to add that when running?

Comment: @Jinx, you have to set the classpath somehow. You could create a Bash script (for *nix) or a batch script (for windows). Also, you could create an uberjar with the gson.jar included and make the jar executable.

Comment: @Jeremy Can't I somehow call upon that jar file directly inside my java class or set path? This is kind of messy. I don't even want to know how would execution command look like if I have many dependencies.

Comment: @Jinx, This is why other tools like IDE's, Maven, and Ant were created. They simplify this for you.

Comment: @Jeremy Yes, yes, I know. But I was hoping that I can just do things like in C and include couple of header files or some magicall command like `javac -tojar  -dependencies "gson,..." MyClass.java`

Answer (score 0):

set the classpath to include both the current directory (`.`) (so the compiler finds your class) and the *gson-2.2.1.jar* (so the compiler finds classes within that jar)

The classpath is just like the `PATH` evnrionmental variable and you will need different separators for different operating systems (`:` for *nix and `;` for Windows) -- at least for *javac*

For *javac* you can set the classpath directly by specifyin the `-cp` option.  Alternatively, set the `CLASSPATH` environmental variable (just like you would for the `PATH` env. var.)